# How to compute $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3}, \sqrt[3]d)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d$ not a cube. I would like to compute a $\theta \in O_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3}, \sqrt[3]d)}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{3}, \theta] = O_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3}, \sqrt[3]d)} $. 
There is an explicit formula for this $\theta$? 
Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Keith Conrad has a series of very nice notes on the splitting fields of $x^3-d$ for $d = 2, 3, 5, 6,7 $ at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/